# How to compare the value in JSON based on the key C++

Tags: c++, json, casablanca

```
web::json::value obj;

obj[JSONKeyRequest] = web::json::value::string(JSONValueRequest);
```

I create a JSON value, and insert some key and values to it.
Then I get this obj in another function, trying to check that whether obj[JSONKeyRequest] equals to "abc", but it doesn't work:

```
web::json::value getObj = this->GetSendObj();
if (getObj[JSONKeyRequest] == web::json::value::string(L"abc"))
{
}
```

However, VC keeps shows:"Errors:No operators [] matches this operands , operand types are const web::json::value[std::wstring]
So, how could I get the value based on the key and compare the value with a string ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if (getObj.at(key) == web::json::value::string(L"abc"))
```

This one works for me.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the error tells you what exactly the arguments should be.

**json** requires **wstring** arguments, or if not wstring, you can input literals.

```
obj[L"JSONKeyRequest"] = web::json::value(L"JSONValueRequest");
```

should work.

Secondly, for comparison try declaring a **wstring** first and then comparing like

```
wstring temp = "abc";
if (getObj["JSONKeyRequest"] == temp)
{
}
```

This should work.

Comment: JSONKeyRequest is a macro defines a string. The error happens at getObj[JSONKeyRequest] , it points out the error happens to the first brace [  , not because the right side of the equal sign.